# Why my clickup create task api call is not working?

Tags: node.js, api, post, clickup-api

url : https://private-anon-4e46c952c5-clickup20.apiary-mock.com/api/v2/list/11825158/task

```
headers: {
      'Authorization': 'pk_3595428_OWNkeyyyy',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
```

Body

````
{
    "name": "New Task created by apu",
    "description": "New Task Description",
    "status": "Open",
    "priority": 3,
    "due_date":1622341935000,
    "due_date_time": false,
    "time_estimate": 8640000,
    "start_date": 1622428335000,
    "start_date_time": false,
    "notify_all": true,
    "parent": null,
    "links_to": null,
    "check_required_custom_fields": true,
} ```

I get the response status code as 200 but no event is showing up on my clickup.

https://clickup.com/api
````

Comment: You should not post your key in public. Also best to check with ClickUp support as you're testing via their api doc

Comment: @Anton its a random key, I added there because leaving it blank made it looked weird. Thanks for the concern for an internet stranger appreciate it.

Comment: @Anton I am able to fix this, but looks like I am not allowed to ask any more questions, can you help how that works?

Comment: Having the same issue. Ever get it figured out? Looks like it could be a major bug in their API.

Answer (score 1):

Their api documentation is great for some things but if you want an easy out of the box solution for mocking api calls (for any service - not just clickup) I'd recommend Postman. They have all the calls in the documentation pre-written and you can use your personal token to make the calls.

Here's the link to download their postman collection: [Postman Clickup Collection](https://t333.s.clickup-attachments.com/t333/3bf59291-47c0-4f1a-ae91-5d9f26a8daca/ClickUp%20API%20V2.postman_collection.json)

Answer (score 1):

Basically in ClickUp the structure is Folder => List => Task.
By default, all List in your Folder are having todo as a status.

But you are giving the status: "Open", which the List doesn't have that type of status.

Before you are giving any status or custom fields you need to create them in the UI manually. Then you have to give the same when you are creating a task.
If you have any doubt mail me at jagadeesh.aleti955@gmail.com.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32604422)

Comment: Actually, it did answer the question for me. I had a similar issue and this was the resolution